# Get hostname from request in Play Framework. Security issue?

Tags: security, request, playframework-2.2

I am using Play 2.2 and I need to send emails containing a link back to my application (for signup purposes).
For now the email is triggered by an API (which basically says "I want to request access to this app"). An email is received by the admin who can accept or deny the request, with a once token mechanism for security.

I am using reverse routing and the absoluteURL() method to determine what the url I need to insert in the email is. This can't be hardcoded because the app runs on different environment / domain names so I want this to be dynamic.

However absoluteURL uses the request as an implicit parameter and get the URL from the Host header. It's possible to forge a request with a different "Host" header and send it to my app, which can result in an email having a link like http://evil.com/acceptRequest?token=gfdklhggfd
The token being legit since it was actually generated by my application.

Is there a better way to do this without security issues ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to pass the host-name as part of the configuration - if each environment runs effectively as separate application.

For example in application.conf

```
hostName=${HOST_NAME}
```

And then set the environment variable `HOST_NAME` for the script that runs the play server.

That being said -- what could an attacker achieve with a forged URL? Could an access key or the like be re-used for another host? That is where I would try to make things secure.

Comment: Yes this is the best alternative I think, it seemed not so flexible when I first thought about it but in the end it should be fine.
About the forged url, it could potentially lead an attacker to trick the administrator of an account to grant him access to his secure account.
But you are right that there is here another security issue independent from this host thing that needs to be addressed.
This question was more of a general one about the average level of security using request headers to determine hostname in Play.
Thanks for your answer !